# Javascript regex to match non repeating 9 digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a string of number for non repeating numbers and a count match in JavaScript using regex

Use case :

1. The string should have only numbers.
2. The string should only be of length 9
3. The string should not have two same numbers

Example :

123456789 should be valid

123456788 should be invalid - Same number not allowed twice

12345678 should be invalid - Doesn't have 9 numbers

1234567890 should be invalid - Has more than 9 numbers

I used below code to find a count match but don't know how to check for non repeating numbers

`/(^\d{9}$)/`

Comment: Repeating number consecutive or repeating numbers in general? For example, is `123436789` valid (two 3's)? I'm assuming no duplicates allowed for full string

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656708/check-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string-javascript

Comment: You can use `^(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)\d{9}$` assuming no duplicates for full string allowed.

Comment: For blocking adjacent repeats use `^(?!\d*(\d)\1)\d{9}$`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205653/regex-to-find-numbers-with-unique-digits

Comment: Imo `^(?=\d{9}$)(?!.*(.).*\1)` with `RegExp.prototype.test()` is the best option. (in particular because too long strings fail before testing the negative lookahead).