# Backreferencing something without putting it in the rest of the expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to make a regular expression that will match all words that have a letter that repeats at least an arbitrary number of times.

For example, if I want to match words that have a letter that repeats at least 3 times, I would want to match words like

```
applepie banana insidious
```

I want to be able to change the number of repeats I'm looking for by just changing one number in my expression, so expressions that only work for a certain number of repeats are not what I'm looking for.

Currently, this is what I'm using

```
^(?=.*(.))(?=(.*\1){4}).*$
```

Where 4 is the number of repeats, a number that I can change to whatever number of repeats I'm looking for.

The above regular expression appears to work, but using a lookahead just so I can use a capturing group seems very unwieldy, and so I'm looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Boderline duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515936/find-words-without-repeated-characters-using-php-regex/26519014#26519014)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will eliminate one lookahead:

```
\b(?=\w*(\w)(\w*\1){2})\w*
```

Start of word, then any number of word-characters such that they consist of any number of word characters, a particular word character, and then any number of characters and that character again, repeated at least twice.

For four repetitions, use `{3}` (for `n` repetitions, use one less).

Also, feel free to replace `\b...` with `^...$` as you were doing if you meant to match whole lines and not words in text.

Comment: +1 I did my solution without looking at the answers. `\b(?=\w*(\w)(?:\w*\1){2})\w+` good thing I saw yours before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\b\w*?(\w)(?=(?:\w*?\1){2})\w*\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jN7oE9/2)

Where `2` is `n-1` for `n` repetitions you're trying to find in a complete word.