# regex: do not allow character appear more than 2 consecutively

Tags: regex

I want to have a regex expression do that.

- string = 12345 => true
- string = 11145 => false, because we do not allow any character appear consecutively, this example is the 1.
- string = aaa664 => false, it is because of a.

I need regex to do it for both character and digit, please help.

Comment: You may find an answer in this one also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870489/regex-to-match-a-word-with-unique-non-repeating-characters?

Comment: @murtazat That's not the same as this one. You can have duplicate character as long as they are not consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (preg_match('/(.)\\1{2}/', $value)) {
    return 'NOT OK';   //invalid
    } else {
    return 'OK';  //valid
    }
```

here is the answer!

Comment: Your answer will detect any character repeated 3 times in a row, but not twice in a row - Are you sure that is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!.*(.)\1+).*$
```

This should so it for you.See demo.The `lookahead` makes sure there is no `.` which is repeated again.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/21

Comment: hi, i can only detect 111aa , that's in the front of the string, how about in the middle of the string, i.e  aa111 ?

Comment: @user2617403 it will detect at all levels.See demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally use a capture group and back reference to detect consecutive characters. For example, in `grep`:

```
$ echo abc | grep '\([a-z]\)\1'

$ echo abbc | grep '\([a-z]\)\1'
abbc
```

The parentheses around the thing you're looking for *capture* the resultant matching portion and this portion is then substituted for `\1` in the remainder of the regex.

In terms of your specific test cases, see below:

```
$ echo 12345 | grep '\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)\1' >/dev/null; echo $?
1
$ echo 11145 | grep '\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)\1' >/dev/null; echo  $?
0
$ echo aaa664 | grep '\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)\1' >/dev/null; echo $?
0
```

You can see you get `1` for a successful string, `0` for a bad one (that matches the regex).

Depending on what language you're using, the methods to detect a match or not may change slightly but the overall concept of capture group and back reference should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex allows negation, just negate the match of `(.)\1`

Given:

```
$ echo "$e"
12345 => true
11145 => false
aaa664 => false
```

Now with perl, only print if no match to `(.)\1`:

```
$ echo "$e" | perl -lne 'print if !/(.)\1/'
12345 => true
```

(or `$ echo "$e" | perl -lne 'print unless /(.)\1/'`)

Same thing with sed:

```
$ echo "$e" | sed -n '/\(.\)\1/!p'
12345 => true
```

grep:

```
$ echo "$e" | grep -v '\(.\)\1'
12345 => true
```

If you do not negate the match, the lines that do have repeated letters with print:

```
$ echo "$e" | grep  '\(.\)\1'
11145 => false
aaa664 => false
```