# Regex find() not true; detect duplicate characters in string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect if there are any duplicate characters in a string using regex. When I test the pattern and input in an online regex tester, it says find() should be true. But it doesn't work in my program.
I'm using info from: [regex to match a word with unique (non-repeating) characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870489/regex-to-match-a-word-with-unique-non-repeating-characters).

What's happening? Am I using regex correctly in Java?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.).*\1");
        String s = "1112";
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) System.out.println("Matches");
        else System.out.println("No Match");
     }
}
```

[image: Regex tester screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backreference needs to be escaped

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.).*\\1");
```