# Make Java regex '[abc]+' match once per letter

Tags: java, regex

```
String[] words = {"a","ab","ac","abc","aac","aa"};
for(String str:words)   {
    if(str.matches("[abc]+"))  {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This code print out

> a,ab,ac,abc,aac,aa

This is almost what I want except I do not want a letter be matched twice. I want to change the regex `[abc]+` so that the match will only happen once. The `aac` and `aa` should not printed because `aa` is matched twice.
Can I do this?

Comment: Do you only have 3 single chars in real life scenario? If yes, and the example above is a very simplified example of what is really needed, then regex is not the best tool for this task.

Comment: Unless there's an artificial requirement to use a regular expression, I'd say you're way better off doing this procedurally by creating a method that iterates over the characters in the string and puts them into a `Set`, failing if it detects a duplicate (if [Set.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add\(E\)) returns false).

Comment: I think your issue is similar to :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870489/regex-to-match-a-word-with-unique-non-repeating-characters

Comment: What about "aca"?

Comment: This sounds like a problem for negative lookahead - not pure regexp

Comment: Not everything that can be done with a regex should be.

Comment: @xBATx, thank you - starting the closing process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative lookahead you can use this regex:

```
^(?:([abc])(?!.*\1))+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgKpUM/1)

If you want to allow any character not just `[abc]` then use:

```
^(?:(.)(?!.*\1))+$
```

- `(.)` matches and groups any character
- `(?!.*\1)` is negative lookahead that asserts for each character captured, that the same character does not exist ahead of the current position.
- `(?:...)+` groups matching character and lookahead in a non-capturing group which is repeated 1 or more times to match whole string.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a Regex and if you're only allowed to use [abc], it's pretty easy to check all the possibilities :D.

```
String[] words = { "a", "ab", "ac", "abc", "aac", "aa" };
for (String str : words) {
    if (str.matches("(abc|ab|acb|ac|a|bac|ba|bca|bc|b|cab|ca|cba|cb|c)")) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could check if the String matches `[abc]+` but doesn't contain `"([a-c]).*\\1"`

Answer (score 0):

Is `ab?c?` what you're looking for?

Comment: No, letters probably aren't sorted. `bca` should match.