# How to match Exactly two characters in a string at anywhere

Tags: python, regex

How to match exactly two same  characters in a string like '4003', '1030'.

```
import re
s='1030'
if re.search('0{2}',s):
print(True)
```

But the above code matches only '1002' butnot '1030'

Comment: Must you use regex?

Comment: You're basically doing the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870489/regex-to-match-a-word-with-unique-non-repeating-characters).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide additional context such as: 1) Is the length of the string always 4? 2) Does it have to be any 2 characters or ones that you can specifically hardcode (for example, specifically for 0, etc)

Comment: Does a word like `aabb` match the criteria of "exactly 2 same characters" or not? Depending on how you look at it, that could be construed as "4 identical characters".

Answer (score 1):

Assume you don't have to use regex:

Note that a string with 4 characters have exactly a pair of duplicating character if and only if it has 3 unique characters. So:

- Make a set of its characters
- Check if there are 3 distinct elements in the set.

Comment: You can't use a set to determine if a character appears *exactly* twice. For example, both `ab` and `abb` would be turned into `{'a', 'b'}`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That's the point of the explanation. "Note that a string with 4 characters have exactly a pair of duplicating character if and only if it has 3 unique characters. ". I don't directly check for "a character appear exactly twice", I check for "there are 3 distinct characters".

Comment: Well it's still wrong because `aabb` matches the criteria and doesn't have 3 distinct characters.

Comment: @Aran-Fey OP said that "exactly two same characters" ... well I guess flag to close the question is better. That can be interpreted in multiple different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use `regex`? Just use `.count()`

```
>>> '1002'.count('0')
2
>>> '1030'.count('0')
2
>>> '2002200220'.count('20')
3
```

Comment: OP doesn't say that the duplicate character is guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: Hmmm I thought that too, but their example has '0{2}' hardcoded so I figured this was specifically their use case. Let's wait on clarification from the user

Comment: My requirement is,able to find exactly  two zeros in a 4 digit number. Can you give me regex slolution?

Answer (score 0):

This code sniped just checks if f.e. index 3 from the string `number1` is equal to the index 3 from the string `number2`.

```
 number1 = '1002'
 number2 = '1030'
 counter = 0

 for i in number1:
     if number1[counter] is number2[counter]:
        print("It's a match")
     counter = counter + 1
```